# unable to get proper reply from PHP to android

Tags: php, android, android-studio

I am creating an app for which I have to maintain a table(login registration), for connecting my android app to the table I am using PHP.

Android code

```
     try {
             JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
              boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
              if (success) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, Login.class);
          RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
      } else if(!success)
         {   JSONObject jsonResponse2 = new JSONObject(response);
           String errval = new String();
         errval=jsonResponse2.getString("errval");
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
         builder.setMessage(errval)
         .setNegativeButton("retry", null)
            .create()
            .show();
     }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error submitting registration", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


  PHP code:-
  require 'config.php';
  $file = 'outfile.txt';
   if ($_POST) {
file_put_contents($file,"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
foreach ($_POST as $KEY => $VAL) {
    file_put_contents($file,$KEY."=>".$VAL."\n", FILE_APPEND);
            }
if (@$_POST["Email_id"] and @$_POST["hash"]) {
    $email = strtolower($_POST["Email_id"]);
    $username = strtolower($_POST["Username"]);
    $hash = $_POST["hash"];
    $echk = $my->Execute("select count(*) from users where email = '$email'");
    if ($echk->fields[0] == 0) {
        $uchk = $my->Execute("select count(*) from users where user = '$username'");
        if ($uchk->fields[0] == 0) {
            $ins = $my->Execute("insert into users values (default,'$username','$email','$hash',default)");
            $error["success"] = true;
            $error["errval"] = "success";
            file_put_contents($file,"success", FILE_APPEND);
        } else {
            $error["success"] = false;
            $error["errval"] = "User: $username already exists";
        }
    } else {
        $error["success"] = false;
        $error["errval"] = "Email: $email already exists";
    }
    } else {
    $error["errval"] = "Missing a key: 'Email_id' or 'hash'";
   }
  file_put_contents($file,"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n", FILE_APPEND);
  $json = json_encode($error);
      print_r($json);
 }
       ?>
```

The details are being entered in the DB without any issues every time, the code also shows if the email is aldready existing in the table, but if the registration is a success, the app throws exception ***Error submitting registration***. cant figure out where the problem is 
thank you.
PS. I am new to stackoverflow still learning, forgive if there are any mistakes in post

Comment: had some issues tagging code sorry for disorientation.

Comment: You should try hand-submitting requests to the PHP code via a web browser, so that you can see what error messages come back. Also, look in the PHP logs for any errors.

Comment: Also, that `e.printStackTrace()` should throw up lots of clues when you're debugging from Android Studio.

Comment: I changed the php code (updated in the question) the php is showing what it received in the text file but isn't showing "success" so I assume that php isn't sending any response to the app when the adding of user details is successful

Comment: Chances are it's a problem with the DB insert query. BTW **don't** interpolate values into the query like that - you're wide open to SQL injection attacks..... use parameters instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (@$echk->fields[0] == 0) {
        $uchk = $my->Execute("select count(*) from users where user = '$username'");
        if (@$uchk->fields[0] == 0) {
            $ins = $my->Execute("insert into users values (default,'$username','$email','$hash',default)");
            $error["success"] = true;
            $error["errval"] = "success";
            file_put_contents($file,"success", FILE_APPEND);
forgot @ in if condition
```